# How do I add the jquery module to a javascript file?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have no html file, I just want my javascript file to understand jquery commands. I tried putting the compressed, production jquery from the [jquery site](http://jquery.com/download/) and adding the line

```
require("./jquery-1.11.0.min");
```

at the top of my javascript file but I still get an

ReferenceError: $ is not defined

error for my $.ajax() call. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you using the PHP `require` method? That doesn't work the same in JS. Use a script tag to add it to your HTML page.

Comment: jQuery does not work in Node.js

Comment: @SLaks — The OP didn't mention Node.js (although it might be implied by the use of `require`, but I was using that in the browser before Node existed). jQuery *does* work in Node anyway, it even has [a package in npm](https://www.npmjs.org/package/jquery).

Comment: @Quentin: Standalone jQuery downloaded from their site won't work without a DOM

Comment: @Quentin. Thanks, this is exactly what I need. Sorry for the confusing language; this is literally day 2 for me of learning javascript.

Comment: @SLaks —  True. Hmm, and "I have no html file" implies that it is probably Node. Although it could still be Rhino or another non-browser based engine. Then again, it could be a browser extension. The question really needs more detail.